# Upgrading a project from react-native to create-react-native-app?

Tags: react-native, create-react-native-app

I'm trying to use `create-react-native-app` as per the documentation with an example project that was built using instructions for `react-native`.

In terms of translating from one to the other what are the steps involved?

Edit: So i can run the app using npm start, with the expo.io QR code appearing as an option etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Create-react-native-app` create a new project with `Expo`, you can eject  it to turn it into a react-native project (android/ios folders with native code + src folder with javascript code).

You'll need an Xcode/Android Studio environment to run a react-native app built without Expo.

You can't use Expo to run a React-Native app with custom native code.

Related links : [Ejecting from Create React Native App](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/EJECTING.md)

[What is the difference between Expo and React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39170622/what-is-the-difference-between-expo-and-react-native)