# Difference between Native Module and React Native Module

Tags: react-native, create-react-app, expo

From official RN [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html);

```
Sometimes an app needs access to a platform API that React Native 
doesn't have a corresponding module for yet.
```

After reading this section I undertsood HOW to create a native module but I am wondering what is the difference between two?

Context:

I was going through [this](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/issues/516) to figure out the difference between react-native init and CRNA and as the folks said, you can't link a native module with CRNA.

```
That led me to question about the difference b/w native module 
and react-native module and why native modules are not compatible with CRNA?
```

Answer (score 0):

Create-react-native-app creates an app within EXPO SDK, where you don't have your own project files, so it's not possible to couple other native modules, unless you eject from EXPO SDK.

If you don't know how expo works, take a look at this link [What is the difference between Expo and React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39170622/what-is-the-difference-between-expo-and-react-native?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)