# Installing react-native-custom-segmented control, need to install ios framework to react-native project

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm trying to install this: https://github.com/wix/react-native-custom-segmented-control into my react-native project.

In the installation instructions, it says to move the `.xcodeproj` file to my project folder. I dragged it to the root folder of my project (though I am not sure that is right).

Then the instructions say to add the `libCustomSegmentedControl.a` file to my target's library.

The project was initialized using expo and I don't think it has a xcode target project? I am confused as to how to proceed in installing this. Is there a secret place in a react-native app that I can find the xcode project?

I'm a beginner with ios so any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you created the project using expo then you need to eject it before you can install any module that expo doesn’t support.

You can find more info at this link. 
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/eject

Expo doesn’t actually have an Xcode or Android project inside the code base, so you can’t add react-native-custom-segmented-control to an expo project.

This post does a good breakdown of the differences between creating a react-native project using expo or `react-native init`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49324689/5508175