# I need help uploading something to expo

Tags: react-native, github

I want to create my own podcast app.

I found this pre-written code online ([`github.com/diego3g/rocketcasts`](https://github.com/diego3g/rocketcasts)) and want to tweak it in order to create my own app.

How do I upload this code into expo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately that React-Native app was not built using Expo. You can tell because it has ios and android folders in its root directory.

Digging deeper you can see that it uses `react-native-config` as a dependency. This dependency requires access to native code, which Expo does not allow. You would have to go through and remove any dependency that requires native code if you wish to use Expo. This may remove functionality and could take some time to resolve issues.

Also this application was built using `react-native: 0.47.2`. Currently the most recent version of react-native is 0.57.8 with 0.58.0 just around the corner. That is quite a jump to make if you plan on upgrading the react-native version. Upgrading RN is not as simple as just changing a version code.

Similarly the repos last commit was over a year ago. That means that the majority of dependencies will be out of date and will need upgraded. Again, some dependencies aren’t a simple upgrade you would need to check every single one to make sure that it doesn’t cause unforeseen problems.  You would also need to check their compatibility with Expo.

Personally I wouldn’t copy the project. I would look at how they have implemented the functionality and then in a new *react-native* project I would re-implement the functionality. That way all dependencies would be up to date and you would know that it would work.

Going down the path of *editing* an existing project like this one may be quite a challenge.

Either way good luck.

You can find more information about Expo here https://docs.expo.io/

And you can find a good explanation of the differences between Expo and `react-native init` here [What is the difference between Expo and React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39170622/what-is-the-difference-between-expo-and-react-native/49324689#49324689)

Comment: That seems more precise than my answer. +1. Could you add a link to "Expo"?

Comment: @VonC added two links for one Expo and one detailing the differences between Expo and React-Native

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to tweak an existing GitHub repository you don't own is to:

- [fork the repo](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/) (that is a GitHub operation, creating a copy of the repo in your account)
- clone it and modify it: you can then push back to your GitHub fork.