# What is the difference between Expo CLI and React Native CLI?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-cli

> React Native provides two way to create Project.

**First:**

```
npm install -g expo-cli
```

**Second:**

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

so what is different between them and what should be used if we create react native app?

Comment: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/react-native-cli-vs-expo-cli-which-one-do-i-choose-bdf02ea457bf

Comment: A similar answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39170622/what-is-the-difference-between-expo-and-react-native?rq=2