# how can i reduce expo build ios size, it is around 188 MB,

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, expo

I have successfully run the expo build: ios command but the resultant IPA file is close to 188MB which is really strange as the app has only a few pages with listViews etc. What may be the reason for such a huge size? The same build size for Android is only about 22MB.

Comment: If you are building react native app using expo it will be of larger size as it uses several integrated libraries , You can check the comparison of expo vs react native cli in this link to get an idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54862388/what-is-the-difference-between-expo-cli-and-react-native-cli

Comment: Please refer this link also https://medium.com/@aswinmohanme/how-i-reduced-the-size-of-my-react-native-app-by-86-27be72bba640

Comment: your best choice would be to create a new app using the react-native-cli

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem with Expo. Then I Create Project with [Bare workflow in Expo.](https://docs.expo.io/bare/exploring-bare-workflow)

Using these i can still use all feature of Expo like running app using bar-code etc.

With this work flow android and ios folder are created and you have complete control on the project.

Then I build apk and ipa as we do using react-native-cli and Result is APK reduced from 50 MB to 18 MB. And iPA reduced from 190 MB to 5 MB.

Using bare work flow you can use react-native-cli node module as well.

Building ipa and apk using expo build:platform always increase size of build.