# What is the difference between react-native cli and Expo with Bare workflow?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

I am going to build a very big application with multiple complex functionalities. but I am stuck on bellow points -

1. What is the difference between react-native cli and Expo with Bare workflow?
2. what Should I include in my project and why?
3. is expo created by facebook?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am writing this answer after using expo bare workflow for 3months .

I will **recommend to use react-native cli** over expo bare workflow because of bellow regions.

1. Expo bare workflow is not developed by facebook team , so when there is a new *update* in RN Cli, expo takes 1-2 months to add in its workflow .
2. You can not control the size of app because expo includes pre included library in SDK. (minimum prod build  starts from 29MB-38MB)
3. App deployment and coding styling is same in both bare-work flow RN Cli, then why not use React native Cli.
4. Ejecting expo in middle of ongoing project is really painful process.
5. you may (very rarely) face compatibility issue with external lib.
6. upgrading expo is also painful for larger code base app.

**When to use expo bare workflow** 
if you have a really good understanding on react native architecture and you know the depth technical requirements of project. Also you should aware of available expo libraries and how many things you are going to use in your project and you are not bothered about app size too.

Note : expect above points you wont see any difference between RN cli and bare work flow while coding .

Comment: Hi, actually I'm trying to remove Expo from a project and everybody says that `expo prebuild` can do this, but all the libraries and Expo stuff keeps in the project.
How can fully remove Expo from the project?

Comment: Doesn't expo bare workflow make updates easy? I am currently upgrading an Expo bare project and it is as simple as doing `expo update` and then resolving the issues (upgrading libraries that weren't installed via expo cli).

Answer (score 11):

**What is the difference between react-native-cli and Expo with Bare workflow?**

Expo with Bare workflow is basically a react-native-cli app that is already preconfigured in order to support most of the Expo packages (here are the supported API in the bare workflow: https://docs.expo.io/bare/unimodules-full-list/ ). With a bare app, you meet halfway between expo managed and react-native-cli. The main configuration that is already made when initiating a bare app is the setting up of the react-native-unimodules package which is provided by the Expo team (https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/master/packages/react-native-unimodules).

In a bare app, you need Xcode and Android studio just as for a plain react-native-cli app.

In the bare app, you can install most of the Expo packages but you have to follow the specific installation instructions for the bare workflow (e.g: install with npm, linking, pod install, etc...).

Expo bare apps have to be started with the react-native command, they do not use the expo cli after their creation.

Most of the convenient features of expo managed app are missing in the bare workflow but Expo is working on integrating most of them over time.

**what Should I include in my project and why?**

What you should include depends on your needs. A strong analysis of the final goal of the project will let you decide between managed workflow on one side and bare workflow / react-native-cli on the other side.

The choice between bare workflow and react-native-cli is simpler as they are basically the same but bare workflow has some extra configurations already made.

**is expo created by Facebook?**

No, but Expo is recognized by them as a really useful tool for react-native development. (that's why expo is one way of creating app according to the official react-native documentation).

Answer (score 6):

`Expo` is written on top of react-native to overcome the issues and challenges that developers face in the development, When it offers some features then it also has some limitations as well.

## What is the difference between react-native CLI and Expo with Bare workflow?

The key difference between these two is the management of different react-native packages.
Expo holds **almost(not all)** everything that react-native has so instead of installing and managing a module separately it offers everything within the expo, So you don't need to take care separate native modules as and expo will do for you but expo has a limitation that if something new launched in react-native until expo adds it in expo you can't use it.
Another limitation is you can't use a library that requires linking because of expo manages this thing for you and you have a boundary to use libraries that expo supports(Managed workflow).
Expo manages the build system for you, So you don't have to use Android-studio or Xcode for making builds.
It has a limitation about the size, So your app can't be below(Android 2MB, IOS 25MB) to this even if a single screen app.

**Limitations with managed workflow**

1. Not all iOS and Android APIs are available.
2. The SDK doesn't support all types of background code execution
   If you need to keep your app size extremely lean, the managed workflow may not be the best choice.
3. Native libraries to integrate with proprietary services are usually not included in the SDK.
4. The only supported push notification service is the Expo notification service.
5. The minimum supported OS versions are Android 5+ and iOS 10+.
6. Free builds can sometimes be queued.

## Bare workflow

Bare workflow gives you more control over linking native libraries and managing builds.

On the other hand with `react-native CLI` you have the freedom to install anything and size also depends on your app.

In the bare workflow we have full access to the underlying native projects and any native code. It's a "bare" native project with React Native and one or more packages from the Expo SDK installed. Anything that you can do in a native project is possible here.

In the bare workflow, the developer has complete control, along with the complexity that comes with that. You can use most APIs in the Expo SDK, but the build service and easy configuration with app.json are not yet supported. You can refer to tutorials and guides that are oriented towards native iOS and Android apps and React Native for alternatives.

**Limitations with bare workflow**

1. Build service only works in the managed workflow.
2. Configuration must be done on each native project rather than once with app.json

Here is a comparison between these.

https://docs.expo.io/introduction/managed-vs-bare/?redirected#workflow-comparison

## What Should I include in my project and why?

It depends, You have to figure it out everything that you wanted to use inside the app is been supported on the expo, If everything(Every Native Module) is available then it's okay to use expo otherwise if you have to eject in between the development it's a painful process.

## Is the expo created by Facebook?

Officially not, but it has the support of some core developers of react-native.

Here is a link that offers a comparison between these two.

[What is the difference between Expo CLI and React Native CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54862388/what-is-the-difference-between-expo-cli-and-react-native-cli)

Comment: Thanks, are you saying linking a lib does not work for bare workflow too? because as per my understanding bare workflow allows everything  (not sure)

Comment: most of the comparison is made for expo managed workflow (even though the title mentioned bare workflow) while the question explicitly ask about expo BARE workflow and react-native-cli.

Comment: your modified reply still focused way too much on the managed workflow which is not even part of the question...

Comment: If someone can understand the basic difference between expo and `react-native-cli` then it's easy to understand bare workflow too.