# Which is Better To Use React Native CLI Or Expo CLI?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-navigation

Actually, I am a beginner to `react-native` as per my knowledge there are two options for me to install react native that is **react-native CLI and Expo CLI**. I am confused about which is better for beginners for **installation** and usage of **React Native app development** and which has **more support** for beginners

Comment: basically you can use both i started with React native only but when I got to know expo - whenever I need to develop an app i use expo because it is easier to setup and get your simulator running - also there is much that the expo team does / implements for you.

Comment: @yesIamFaded Thank You Sir For Your valuable information and also  which one is the best recomended one for beginners  ( By you )

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between Expo and React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39170622/what-is-the-difference-between-expo-and-react-native)

Comment: @BelginAndroid u can definitly go with expo, if you at some point need to you can always eject.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## React Native CLI:

### Advantages:

- You can add native modules written in Java/Objective-C, so you have full control of your application.

### Disadvantages:

- Needs Android Studio and XCode to run the projects
- You can't develop for iOS without having a mac
- If you want to share the app you need to send the whole `.apk` / `.ipa` file
- Does not provide JS APIs out of the box, e.g. Push-Notifications, Asset Manager, they need to be manually installed and linked with yarn for example.
- Setting up a working project properly take more time.

## Expo:

### Advantages:

- Setting up a project is easy and can be done in a few minutes.
- Sharing the app is very easy (via QR-code or link).
- No build necessary to run the app
- Integrates some basic libraries in a standard project (Push Notifications, Asset Manager, etc.)
- You can eject it to ExpoKit and integrate native code continuing using some of the Expo features, but not all of them
- Expo can build `.apk` and `.ipa` files (distribution to stores possible with Expo)

### Disadvantages:

- You can't add native modules (probably a gamechanger for some)
- You can't use libraries that use native code in Objective-C/Java (eg: `react-native-fbsdk`)
- Large APK Size
- Debugging in ExpoKit (with native modules) is a lot more complicated since it mixes two languages and different libraries.
- Choosing between Expo and React Native CLI depends on your application requirements.

Comment: Thanks sir For Your Information

Comment: This answer feels very similar with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49324689/4110257) from another question with no reference

Answer (score 3):

I prefer React Native CLI, expo has some good things but it has a lot of limitations and probably you will regret to use it in the future.

Check this website:
https://apiko.com/blog/expo-vs-vanilla-react-native/