# setting up flipper but ios android folders are missing (RN 62.2, Expo 37)

Tags: react-native, expo, flipper

I think I saw in a documentation somewhere that they had merged android and ios folder into one and it's now all in index.js file but maybe I dreamed it because I can't find it. I'm trying to setup flipper on my RN project and it's on v62.2 & expo v37 but they are no android or ios folder which is why I am so confused. My project is fully running both on ios and android.

- How could I setup flipper if these folders are gone?
- Didn't expo or RN merge the android & ios folder into the index.js?
- If they are merged then how can I setup flipper?

Edit: So are they any alternative to flipper for layout debugging?

Comment: If you need to add native modules to an Expo project then you will need to eject it to make it a full react-native app. The only way you will see the ios and android folders is in a pure react-native app, Expo abstracts the native folders away from you.

Comment: Is there a way of using flipper with expo? If not, is there an alternative to it?

Answer (score 2):

Flipper requires you to update for [iOS](https://fbflipper.com/docs/getting-started/react-native-ios.html): the podfile and the AppDelegate, for [Android](https://fbflipper.com/docs/getting-started/react-native-android.html): the build.gradle and the MainApplication.

This is manipulating native code. Expo does not allow you to manipulate native code as it is abstracted away from you. To see what the differences between Expo and a "pure" react-native project I suggest reading the answers to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39170622/what-is-the-difference-between-expo-and-react-native) as it should clear up some of your misconceptions.

As Flipper has just been released it is unlikely that these native modifications will be in the current Expo SDK. The Expo 37 SDK uses [React Native 0.61 internally](https://blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-37-is-now-available-dd5770f066a6) which means as this is a feature of `react-native` `0.62.0` it will not be available in `0.61.0`.

To get Flipper working in a current Expo project you would either have to [eject](https://docs.expo.io/workflow/customizing/) and then follow the instructions on the Flipper website for setting it up, or wait for Flipper to be added to the Expo SDK (which could be expedited by adding a [feature request](https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/).