# npx pod-install returns "CocoaPods is not supported in this project"

Tags: react-native, cocoapods, expo, react-native-video, pod-install

Context: I'm trying to create a React Native App with `react-native-video`. The iOs installation instruction starts with `npx pod-install`.

Running:

```
npx pod-install
```

Returns:

```
npx: installed 1 in 1.113s
Scanning for pods...
CocoaPods is not supported in this project
```

The output message is not yet helpful to me. So I went to [npm pod-install](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pod-install). Looks like it abstracts CocoaPods and gem complexity away.

Is there an easier way to resolve this issue than learning CocoaPods and gem?

---

package.json

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~37.0.3",
    "react": "~16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.9.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-37.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-video": "^4.4.5",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "~8.1.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.6"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Can you share your `package.json`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The reason you are getting the error is because you are building your React-Native project with Expo.

Expo extrapolates the native code away from you so that you don't have to deal with native code. Also an Expo project does not allow you to edit native code. Cocoapods add native code to your app, so this is why you are getting your error.

If you wish to use video in an Expo project then you should look at what is provided with Expo, the documentation for video is [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v37.0.0/sdk/video/).

If this doesn't suit your needs and you need to use `react-native-video` then you will need to `eject` your project from Expo so that it becomes a full React-Native project. This is not a step that you should do lightly, and without fully researching it first.

I would also suggest you familiarise yourself with the answers to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39170622/what-is-the-difference-between-expo-and-react-native) that explains the differences between Expo and React-Native

Comment: I've built my project using Expo, and I want to use React Native Paper. It seems that `npx pod-install` is a requirement. what should I do?

Answer (score 4):

***You must check the current folder you are in, make sure you are in root directory of project in termial.***

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below command

```
npm i pod-install
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using expo's video library if you're just running into this issue with react-native-video. Instructions from their docs: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/video/

> > **expo install expo-av**

```
import { Video } from 'expo-av';

<Video
  source={{ uri: 'http://d23dyxeqlo5psv.cloudfront.net/big_buck_bunny.mp4' }}
  rate={1.0}
  volume={1.0}
  isMuted={false}
  resizeMode="cover"
  shouldPlay
  isLooping
  style={{ width: 300, height: 300 }}
/>
```