# TypeError: null is not an object evaluating '_reactNative.NativeModules.RNDateTimePickerManager.getDefaultDisplayValue'

Tags: react-native, datetimepicker

I am not sure if this is an error from my code or it's from the `react-native-datetimepicker`.

Here's how I am using it in my code:

```
{show && (
  <>
    <DateTimePicker
      value={date}
      mode={mode}
      is24Hour={true}
      onChange={dateOnChange}
    />
    <Button
      title="Submit"
      onPress={() => {
        setShow(false);
      }}
    />
  </>
)}
```

`show` is a state, controlled by its mother component. When it's true, the `DateTimePicker` will show.

Here's a more detailed log of the bug:
[image]

#### I am using **expo** btw

Comment: The error show on iOS or android?

Comment: Can you please post your code to show how are you using that package?

Comment: @AnhDevit on iOS

Comment: Are you run pod install?

Comment: @SaachiTech it's kind of long to abbreviate, but I can try. I essentially just choose to show the component based on a condition that's controlled by its root component.

Comment: @AnhDevit I used npm install

Comment: If its an expo project then I think, not entirely sure, that either you will need to eject it in order to use this module or use an alternate module provided by the expo

Answer (score 3):

If you are using expo, this issue occurs if you a running your app on a device that is running on iOS 14.

To fix it, add a display prop on the date picker just like the example below:

```
<RNDateTimePicker display="inline" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this command

```
npx pod-install
```

Comment: Where `ios` ios located?

Comment: I added image for you

Comment: are the ones hightlighted in blue hidden? I can't see them with `ls`

Comment: I am using `expo` btw

Comment: Hmmm If you using expo try to run npx pod-install

Comment: I got CocaoPods not supported in this project

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62424698/npx-pod-install-returns-cocoapods-is-not-supported-in-this-project

Answer (score 0):

Following the code helps me to resolve my issue.

```
jest.mock('@react-native-community/datetimepicker', function () {
    const mockComponent = require('react-native/jest/mockComponent')
    return mockComponent('@react-native-community/datetimepicker')
})
```

A found solution from here

https://github.com/react-native-datetimepicker/datetimepicker/issues/216#issuecomment-741794280