# expo exits on my android phone after it downloaded javascript bundle

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo

I am learning react native currently, I was able to get my dummy application to work on web browser, but when I try to run it on my android device it goes through all steps successfully and once it finished downloading the javascript bundle it stuck for 2 seconds and just exists the expo go application on my android device.

there is not even an error message to search for.

here is what I tried and what you might wanted to know

- my phone and laptop are on the same network (my home wifi)
- I've tried Lan, tunnel, and even local they are all the same
- I've uninstalled expo go from my android device and clicked on run on Android device/simulator this installed expo go application again on my android then tried and it's still the same
- I've also tried to open the firewall to 19000 port and it's still the same
- I've also tried to connect my phone through a usb and clicked on run on Android device/simulator it was a bit faster but same problem
- also tried qrcode scanning

useful information

- my phone is android 11 realme c20

that's all I tried to do, is it just bad luck?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try by scanning the QR code from Expo App?

You can try by creating Virtual Android Device. Watch this video on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gVGuNxkh8ig&ab_channel=ToThePointCode)

Comment: Did you try turning off and on your phone? Maybe your ram is full or something like that?

And I suggest you to use React Native with virtual device instead of Expo. On react native you can do anything you want to do with Expo and you can do more. If you want to go forward with mobile development this would be better for you.

Comment: It is for beginning. If you want to improve yourself on it, react native is better.

Comment: isn't expo just a layer on top of react native, that adds extra features. I am still typing javascript react native code

Comment: You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39170622/what-is-the-difference-between-expo-and-react-native) for that.